# Button is not showing in border layout in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to show a button on a frame in the `north` direction using border layout but the button is not shown on the frame.  There are no compiler errors.

My code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class gui1
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            JFrame frm = new JFrame();

            Button btn = new Button("SUBMIT");

            frm.add(btn,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frm.setSize(800,500);
            frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frm.setVisible(true);
            frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(frm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       }
    }
```

Comment: 1) **Don't** `frm.setSize(800,500);`. It's just a guess. **Do** `frame.pack();` (immediately before setting it visible, but after all components are added). That might fix the problem. 2) Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the frame layout before adding components to the frame.

Comment: you could just comment out the `setLayout` statement as `BorderLayout` is the default layout for a `JFrame`